# How to export csv from data frame converted from list in R

Tags: r, export-to-csv

Here I have a list like this:

```
mylist <- list(
  list(a = 'foo', b = 'bar', c = 'foobar'),
  list(a = 'red', b = 'blue', c = 'gold')
  )
```

I converted this list to dataframe.

```
> mylist <- data.frame(t(sapply(mylist, c)))

> mylist
    a    b      c
1 foo  bar foobar
2 red blue   gold
```

I tried to export to csv file, failed in error:

```
> write.csv(mylist, '/path/to/my/file.csv')
Error in write.table(mylist, "/path/to/my/file.csv",  :
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

How can I convert dataframe converted from the list to CSV?

Comment: You cannot write list to csv. Convert it to dataframe and then use `write.csv`.

Comment: Some of the columns are of type list, hence the error. Try `mylist <- data.frame(t(sapply(mylist, function(x) unlist(x))))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as.data.frame`:

```
mylist <- list(
  list(a = 'foo', b = 'bar', c = 'foobar'),
  list(a = 'red', b = 'blue', c = 'gold')
)
write.csv(as.data.frame(mylist), tempfile("test.csv"))
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.